# Start both http and https with the same project Adonisjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, adonis.js

I would like to have both HTTP and HTTPS running in with my adonisjs project. For now my server.ts looks like this (run https):

```
import 'reflect-metadata'
import sourceMapSupport from 'source-map-support'
import { Ignitor } from '@adonisjs/core/build/standalone'
import { createServer } from "https";
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

sourceMapSupport.install({ handleUncaughtExceptions: false })

const privateKey = readFileSync(join(__dirname + '/sslCert/server.pem'), 'utf8');
const certificate = readFileSync(join(__dirname + '/sslCert/server.cert'), 'utf8');
new Ignitor(__dirname).httpServer().start((handle) => {
    return createServer(
      {
        key: privateKey,
        cert: certificate,
      },
      handle
    );
  });
```

For example, I would like https server to run on port 3333 and http server to run on port 4444.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that it is possible to create an http instance with the same application but in my case I only wanted http for specific routes and https for the others.
So the most optimized way to have an http route is to completely create an instance so we dont have to load https routes alongside http routes that are not going to be used in a http request.